# WinRT - save images from list to folder

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Hi i would like to ask how i can save more than 1 image to folder. I have list with image's URI and i would like to save all images to selected folder. This is my save method, but it save just last image from list. I need to save all images from list with name like img0, img1, img2, img3.

```
private async void saveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Picker = new FileSavePicker();
    Picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
    StorageFile file = await Picker.PickSaveFileAsync();


    foreach (var a in im) // im is list with images uri
    {
        var uri = new Uri(a.ImgUri.ToString());
        Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var stream = await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(uri);
        Stream dataStream = stream.AsStreamForRead();
        using (Stream saveStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {

            await dataStream.CopyToAsync(saveStream);
            await dataStream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one file to write to. Each time you write a image to that file, the file is *overwritten*, so only the last image is saved.

You can fix the bug by simply move the following code block into the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var a in im) // im is list with images uri
{ 
    //Move the code into foreach
    var Picker = new FileSavePicker();
    Picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
    StorageFile file = await Picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    var uri = new Uri(a.ImgUri.ToString());
    ...
}
```